# urllib and regular expression substitution error

Tags: python, regex, escaping, urllib, python-2.7

Why does the following result in an error?

```
import re
from urllib import quote as q
s = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9.: ^*$@!+_?-]')
s.sub(q, "A/B")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/python/python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1236, in quote
    if not s.rstrip(safe):
AttributeError: rstrip
```

I'd like to call sub on strings that contain forward slashes, not sure why it results in this error. How can it be fixed so that I can pass strings with '/' characters in them to sub()?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `re.sub` calls the `repl` parameter with an instance of `re.match`.

I think you want to use:

```
s.sub(lambda m: q(m.group()), "A/B")
```

However, a simpler way of doing this might be to use the `safe` argument to `urllib.quote`:

```
urllib.quote("A/B", safe="/.: ^*$@!+_?-")
```